# Custom elements in standard palette Contao

Tags: contao

Iam using oneo custom elements .I need to add a field for content.Please check my code

```
<?php

return array(
    'label' => array(
        'en' => array('Feature boxe', 'Create an area with text, image/video and background image'),
        'de' => array('Feature-Box', 'Erzeugt einen Bereich mit Text, Bild/Video und Hintergrundbild'),
    ),
    'types' => array('content'),
    'standardFields' => array('cssID', 'headline'),
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'inputType' => 'group',
            'label' => array(
                'en' => array('Image settings'),
                'de' => array('Bildeinstellungen'),
            ),
        ),
        'image' => array(
            'label' => array(
                'en' => array('Feature image or video', 'Choose an image or multiple video files.'),
                'de' => array('Feature-Bild oder -Video', 'Wählen Sie ein Bild oder mehrere Videodateien aus.'),
            ),
    ),
);
```

The new field is appear in a new palette. But I need to add the new one in the same palette as cssID resides.Is it possible ???

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean [RockSolid Custom Elements](https://github.com/madeyourday/contao-rocksolid-custom-elements). And no, that is not possible. Custom fields can only be added in the standard group of the custom element - or to custom groups that you define yourself.

Comment: Yeah I'm using Rocksolid Custom Elements. So I need to extend tl_content for achieving my requirement . Am I right?

Comment: No, I don't think that would work. RockSolid Custom Elements only supports a specific set of `standardFields`.

Comment: I need to add some fileds in the expert settings group of tl_content while selecting the content elements . I extend the field in tl_content , but in which palette I placed the new field.Didn't find any palette for content element.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do now. Your original question is about the configuration of a RockSolid Custom Element and whether you can put a field into the same group as `cssID` resides for instance - which is not possible.

Comment: I need to add an extra field into the same group as cssID resides of tl_content while I selecting rocksolid custom element. But it is not possible.So I tried to extend tl_content.Again I failed in paletted selection.

Comment: I think you need to do that via an `onload_callback`.